# Прокрутка текста + восстановление места последнего чтения

Tags: android

Я успешно делал приложения на основе ХТМЛ, но тут как я и ожидал пришел к тому что при таких приложениях нельзя делать восстановление при следующем запуске приложения места где закончил читать. На днях снова ринулся в поиски как сделать тест с прокруткой и чтоб приложение запоминало последнее место и при запуске его восстанавливало.

Был бы благодарен за готовые куски кода чтоб вот, например, для Активити: "......" а вот для мейн "......". Просто не особо шарю. Нашел в нете как сделать текст с прокруткой, но там расчитано на уже шарящего пользователя, а мне "создай там то и тд.." ниче не дает и не понятно. Если вы в этом разбираетесь то вам минута дела, а я был бы безмерно благодарен.

Может сделать еще книгу не скроллингом на одной странице, а свайпами между отдельными страницами текста, но как так сделать чтоб не приходилось вручную на каждую страницу кидать текст + для разных экранов разное количество текста нужно.

Comment: поучить android API надо. это основы. без этого ну никак. и конечно же великий и могучий язык Java. PS незнал что можно делать АПК с помощью хтмл'а...

Comment: Через вебвиев выводить просто не интернет адрес а вставлять ссылку на локальный файл вот таким макаром: webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

Answer (score 3):

Не могу понять в чем конкретно проблема? И да вопрос немного неформатный.

Берете четыре события.

1. Загрузка приложения => загрузить хэш таблицу из файла.
2. Событие открытия документа. Посчитать хэш читаемого документа(ключ). Извлечь из хэш таблицы номер страницы по ключу. Переключить на эту страницу. Если документ еще ни разу не открывали просто добавить в табилцу новую запись с номером страницы 0.
3. Событие закрытия документа => сохранить в хэш табилцу по уже посчитанному ключу( хэш читаемого документа) - значение(номер текущей страницы).
4. Завершение приложения => сохранить хэш табилцу в файл.

Все. Код писать  мне лень.